# linq to sql - Handle empty column of type XML

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I'm using linq to read from a DB with 2 column containing XML(column type is xml)
My problems is that if the xml column is empty or the xml is not valid.

I get errors like "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1" or "missing root element". 
The errors are correct because the xml is bad but how to I get into the loop so I can handle the error correctly.. 
Now the error happens as soon I start the foreach loop and therefore I cant handle the error on the seperate row/item

```
 var approvedList = from a in db.FormApproveds
                       join error in db.ErrorReportingForms
                       on a.FFormFilled_Id equals error.FormFilled_Id
                       join ff in db.FormFilleds on error.FormFilled_Id equals ff.Id
                       where error.ErrorString == "no error" && ff.CreationDate.Year == year && formIds.Contains(ff.FormTemplate_Id) 
                       select new { FormApproved = a, ErrorReportingForm = error, formName = error.FormName, FormFilled = ff };
 foreach (var item in approvedList) {} //error happens here
```

[image: Error here]

[image]

Comment: In what exact place the exception is thrown? `approvedList` is a `List` so iterating it shouldn't give an error.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the error

Comment: What type is `approvedList` then?  I see it's commented out.

Comment: approvedList is a joined list of multible tables, but the problem comes from a single table(ErrorReportingForms) that contains the xml columns.

Comment: So please show the definition of `approvedList`. Is it just `db.ErrorReportingForms` without `ToList` ?

Comment: linq query to create approvedList added in post

Comment: Where is this xml column? And how it's mapped in your code. Can you show the model classes with xml property also?

Comment: i'ved added a screen of the dbml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because LINQ provider tries to initiate `XElement` from a db column and when it's not valid an exception is thrown before the model object is created. To solve this try set mapping types of xmls to `string` instead of `XElement` and convert it to `XElement` later. You can create additional partial class and define methods for parsing those xmls:

```
public partial class ErrorReportingForm
{
    public XElement GetInXml() => XElement.Parse(InXml);

    public void SetInXml(XElement e) => InXml = e.ToString();
}
```

That's only an example. You can try to define some properties instead.

Then you can wrap it with try-catch block:

```
try
{
    var inXml = item.ErrorReportingForm.GetInXml();
}
catch (...)
{

}
```

Comment: It works great.. Thank you.. I've just created a method to convert the xml string to either a Xelement or Null and the check on that when using the value